# hide iframe but show ask box on tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr

so I'm working on a page for tumblr where I'm including an ask box but I'd like the controls at the top to be hidden. I'm using `iframe {display:none !important;}` but it's also hiding my ask box. How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to target the specific class name of the iframe you want to hide/show. Something like `.tmblr-controls { display: none; }` I can't remember the exact class name, but it will be easy to find. Or you could still use what you have, and in addition find the class name for the ask iframe and set that to `.iframe-ask {display: block; }` whatever that class name is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, css:

```
iframe {
   display: none !important;
}

#ask_form {
   display: block !important;
}
```